# I would like to catch the image from RSS feed

Tags: python, django, rss, feedparser

I'm executing these lines:

views.py

```
def pull_feed(feed_url, posts_to_show=5):
    feed = feedparser.parse(feed_url)
    posts = []
    for i in range(posts_to_show):
        pub_date = feed['entries'][i].updated_parsed
        published = date(pub_date[0], pub_date[1], pub_date[2] )
        posts.append({
            'title': feed['entries'][i].title,
            'summary': feed['entries'][i].summary,
            'link': feed['entries'][i].link,
            'content': feed['entries'][i].content,
            'date': published,
        })
    return {'posts': posts}
```

my_template.html

```
       {% for post in posts.posts %}
                <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
                {{ post.content }}
                <hr/>
       {% endfor %}
```

But I would like to have something like **post.image** or catch the image (of the RSS blog) from the post.content, because it gives me the following **result**:

```
[{'base': u'http://websiteexample.com/feed/', 'type': u'text/html', 'value': u'<p><a href="http://websiteexample.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/imageexample.png">}]
```

How can I get the image from RSS? I will save it in my database later and make something like a post replication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use python's re module to parse out the first url in the content 'value' field that looks like an image (ie has an extension like png/jpeg/jpg)

```
import re

# inside your for i in range(posts_to_show) loop:
value = feed['entries'][i].content[0]['value']
image_url = re.search('(?P<url>http?://[^\s]+(png|jpeg|jpg))', value).group("url")
```

then you can append the image_url to your post:

```
posts.append({
        'title': feed['entries'][i].title,
        'summary': feed['entries'][i].summary,
        'link': feed['entries'][i].link,
        'content': feed['entries'][i].content,
        'date': published,
        'image_url': image_url,
    })
```

Comment: What should I type on the 'value' string? because i get the following error: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: I updated my answer, 'value' is a key in the dictionary you get from post.content, missed the part where the dictionary is actually inside square brackets so it's actually a list of dictionaries (or a list with one single dictionary) so must drill into that list index to get at the 'value' so it's like: post.content[0]['value']